# Zend Framework - Display form from different view

Tags: php, zend-framework, forms

I have a `LoginController`, `Login Model` and `Login View` that matches.
On the `login.phtml` file I can use `<?php $this->form; ?>` to output the form as specified in the Login model.

I would like to however place this same "view" into the `index.phtml` file that has a different class and model etc..

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use partial view helper when some html is shared between different views.

Edit:

I forgot to wrote that there is also an action helper called viewRenderer that can be used to render different view script than the default one. For example, you could load login.phtml in your indexAction as follows:

```
    $this->view->form = $yourForm;
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoController(true); // to specify that login.phtml is in different controller than your indexAction (in necessary)
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer('login/login'); // assuming login.phtml is in login controller folder
```

Comment: Hi Marcin, thank you for the response. I have used the above code in my IndexController indexAction() function, how would i call this on the index.phtml file to display the form? I keep getting "Notice: Undefined variable: yourForm" on the page.

Comment: @mediox. In your login.phtml you have $this->form;. Hance, you need to make form variable in the indexAction. $yourForm is the form to be displayed in the view. I don't know the actual name of the variable in your code, I used  $yourForm as an example.